How to get build for wlroots to find runtime dependency wayland
I'm trying to build wlroots from source, and I get the following error when running meson:
meson setup build/
...
Run-time dependency wayland-server found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
Looking for a fallback subproject for the dependency wayland-server

meson.build:106:17: ERROR: Neither a subproject directory nor a wayland.wrap file was found.

I've already built wayland, and the *.so files are installed locally to the install/ directory under my home directory.
How do I tell the meson build where to find wayland?

Add this:
my_dep = declare_dependency(link_with : my_lib, include_directories : my_inc)

For more info on adding your dependency, check:
https://mesonbuild.com/Dependencies.html
